# PSQL: SSL error: unknown protocol

Tags: postgresql, ubuntu, ssl, psql

all. I have a new Ubuntu 17.04 server setup. I can access it through ssh successfully. Also, I have a postgresql database installed. It is already configured to accept remote connections through the following configurations:

pg_hba.conf

```
host all all 0.0.0.0/0  md5
```

postgresql.conf

```
listen_addresses = '*'
```

But when I try to access the database from my computer, I get the following error:

```
psql -h [SERVER_IP]  -d db_production -U dbuser 
psql: SSL error: unknown protocol
expected authentication request from server, but received S
```

I also have a docker container running inside the server. If I access it through /bin/bash and also try to connect with the server db, I get this error:

```
psql -h [SERVER_IP]  -d db_production -U dbuser
psql: could not connect to server: Connection refused
    Is the server running on host "[SERVER_IP]" and accepting
    TCP/IP connections on port 5432?
```

The port 5432 is opened and the firewall is disabled. Does anybody have gone through that?

Answer (score 0):

First, do you use the local server host when you're connected into the docker? The server IP, in that case, should be `localhost` or `127.0.0.1`.

Try to use the complete DB URL:

`psql postgres://dbuser:dbPass@SERVER_IP:5432/dbname?sslmode=prefer`