# psql: SSL error: certificate verify failed

Tags: heroku, heroku-postgres

I'm encountering a frustrating problem connecting to Heroku Postgres using `psql` and in `psycopg2`, on `sslmode=require`.

When connecting with the next examples on debian (python 2.7.13) I'm encountering the same problem of

```
psql: SSL error: certificate verify failed
```

psql:

```
psql "host=<MyHost> sslmode=require" --port=5432 --username=<MyUser> --password
```

Psycopg2:

```
import psycopg2
db_url =  "postgres://User:Pwd@Host:5432/DB?sslmode=require"
psycopg2.connect(db_url)
```

I tried to change the `postgresql.conf` and `pg_hba.conf` as described here:
[PSQL: SSL error: unknown protocol](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48216570/psql-ssl-error-unknown-protocol)

No Luck.

My versions:

```
psycopg2=-2.6.2
OpenSSL=1.1.0j  20 Nov 2018
postgres=9.6
```

Answer (score 22):

Ok. I figured out that in my system, somehow there is a `root.crt` file in the `~/postgresql` dir. The `.crt` file made the whole problem (it wasn't certificated to Heroku) and when I deleted it, the connection worked.

FYI

Comment: It seems the pg_dump have no option to specify ssl cert using parameter or shell variable PGSSLROOTCERT.
So I have to put my cloud provider ssl cert into ~/.postgresql/root.crt